# Which router handles incoming request first in a mixed routing scenario

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-routing

I understand for conventional routing, the request first hit mvcmiddleware, then the router will compare the request to the predefined templates.

if it find one that matches, the route values are extracted from the request and assigned to route parameters of the selected template. The controller and action route parameters is what is then used to find the route for the request.

Whilst on the other hand attribute routes urls are calculated at runtime and stored in a dictionary as a key value pair of url and an associated action, and when a request hits mvcmiddleware, it checks if the request url is a key in the dictionary and invokes the associated action.

But as the request hits mvcmiddleaware where we have both route types defined, which of the routers tends to handle the request first?

Comment: Please read this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing) of this ASP.NET Routing article.

Comment: I have , but it doesnt answer my question about which router attempt to handle a request first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding both conventional and attribute based routing use a middleware. I would assume that the routing rules evaluation follows the middleware registrations. So if the routing based middleware is configured first (`UseRouting`) then its rules should be evaluated first.

In order to make sure, which one get evaluated first I would suggest to use a Route Debugger, like [this](https://github.com/EdiWang/Edi.RouteDebugger), [blog post](https://edi.wang/post/2020/4/29/my-aspnet-core-route-debugger-middleware). With this by calling the `UseRouteDebugger` you would be able to see the resolved routing rule in the response header.

Comment: you mean to say conventional routing has it own middleware and attribute routing also has its middleware?

Comment: @GodfredBoateng Yes indeed. Conventional: In case of .NET Core 2.x there was an extension method called `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute`. In case of .NET Core 3.x you have to use `UseMvc` with `UseEndpoints`. Attribute: in case of .NET Core 2.x there was the `UseEndpointRouting` in .NET 3.x there is the `UseRouting`. Please check the following files' source code for more details: `MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions`, 
`EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions`

Comment: My bad, when you mentioned middleware, my mind went straight to the pipeline it self, of course, attribute routing and conventional will have their own middleware. You answers satisfies my question. Thanks for the time.

Comment: @GodfredBoateng If it satisfies your question then would you be so kind and mark it as answer. Thanks mate.